# Can we predict a rating based on text, using NLP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I've used regression and classification in the past to train, test, and make predictions.  Now, I am looking at some NLP sample code and everything is running fine, but at the end, I was hoping to make a prediction of a 'rating' score based on what is contained in a 'text' field.  Maybe NLP can't do this, but it seems like it should be doable.  Here is the code that I am testing.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tf=TfidfVectorizer()
text_tf= tf.fit_transform(df['review_text'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text_tf, df['reviews.rating'], test_size=0.3, random_state=123)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn import metrics
# Model Generation Using Multinomial Naive Bayes
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted= clf.predict(X_test)
print("MultinomialNB Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predicted))
# around 7% accurate...
```

Now, based on specific text, I want to predict the rating a customer will give.

```
y_predicted = clf.predict(text_tf["Didnt know how much i'd use a kindle so went for the lower end. im happy with it, even if its a little dark"])
```

Then I get this error: `IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2`

The actual rating for this actual review is 4.  I was expecting 'y_predicted' to show me a 4.  Maybe there is some other library for this kind of thing.  Again, I think it should be doable.  Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any connection between your title, body, and conclusion. Yes, it's possible to predict ratings. Yes, it's doable. No, it doesn't make this library unqualified for this task. Your mistake is an indexing error, nothing more. It doesn't say anything about the possibility of the task. Are you sure you can index `TfidfVectorizer` like a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is what you're asking it to predict on.

Text_tf is a matrix of size (n_samples, n_features). This is what you trained your model on. It doesn't have any text in it anymore. What you want is to transform your test sample the same way you did your training samples, using the TfidfVectorizer. Try the following:

```
y_predicted = clf.predict(tf.transform("Didnt know how much i'd use a kindle so went for the lower end. im happy with it, even if its a little dark"))
```

Comment: I think that idea is close.  However, when I tried this: y_predicted = clf.predict(TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform("Didnt know how much i'd use a kindle so went for the lower end. im happy with it, even if its a little dark"))
I got this: ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.
Also, when I tried this: y_predicted = clf.predict(TfidfVectorizer.transform("Didnt know how much i'd use a kindle so went for the lower end. im happy with it, even if its a little dark")) I got this: TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_documents'

Comment: Did you try the exact code I gave you? `tf` is a trained instance of TfidfVectorizer.

Comment: Yes, I tried it just as you posted it.  I got this error: ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.

Comment: I guess it needs a list: `y_predicted = clf.predict(tf.transform(["Didnt know how much i'd use a kindle so went for the lower end. im happy with it, even if its a little dark"]))`

Comment: It runs, but it gives me a 5 for all the text reviews I enter.  Even when I know a rating is 1 and I enter the exact text that is associated with that 1 rating, I get a 5.  Something is definitely off here.  I'll research further.  Thanks.